# the reason of square bracket in scapy

Tags: python, list, scapy

i am a newbie in python, would appreciate your explanation.

i would like to know the reason of the square bracket in which we have passed 0 at the end of this function.
is it because the function return a list?

```
answered_list = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast,timeout=1,verbose=False)[0]
```

regards

Comment: Yes; it's a subscript.  If you suspected that, why did you not investigate that suspicion.  You *do* know what you're doing this far.  :-)

Comment: @Prune - tuple unpacking isn't obvious to a beginner. How you can have one or two variables on the left hand side and maybe a subscript on the right can be confusing. `scrapy.srp` examples usually unpack the results, this example doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

`srp` returns a tuple of `ans_result` and `unans_result`. You use [0] for ans_result.

If you want to unpack both, use:

```
ans, unans = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast,timeout=1,verbose=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python can unpack tuples and lists into individual variables on assignment. For instance:

```
a,b,c = [1,2,3]
```

Your command returns a tuple of 2 items. In most examples, you'll see something like

```
answered, unanswered = scapy.srp(...)
```

`srp` returned a 2 tuple and python expanded that into the two variables. But if you don't care about the unanswered ones, you can just take the first value of this 2 tuple

```
answered = scapy.srp(...)[0]
```